# How would you recommend parsing a private bitcoin core node with nodeJS?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, full-node

I just need to parse a private node and lookup one bitcoin address and get all transactions going in or out of the address preferably using nodeJS within the last 200 or so blocks. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad as parsing a node involves decoding every transaction within a block(which would require `txindex` to be enabled), and recording each output and input until you end up with a list of all outputs that have not been used as an input aka an unspent output.

With a fully synced node and `txindex=1` you can begin iterating through each block of the last 200 blocks with loops using the rpc calls `getblockhash` `getblock` `getrawtransaction` and `decoderawtransaction`, storing the outputs in a database. On each new block you should check every input to see if there is a transaction id matching an output in your existing output database, if there is that output has been spent. The [node-bitcoin JSON-RPC wrapper](https://github.com/freewil/node-bitcoin) should work fine for implementing these calls to your node. As you can imagine this would take some time.

Comment: Can you explain what "parsing a node" means here?  Sounds like you mean something like parsing every block in the blockchain?